# jQuery dropdown plugin - How to know if dropdown is open or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am using this plugin for jQuery: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/

I want to do something when hovering a div element IF dropdown is currently open, or something else if dropdown is currently closed while hovering the div element.

Psuedo code:

```
$('#foo').hover(function() {
    if ( $('*').dropdown('is_visible') ) {
        alert('Dropdown is visible, so do something...');
    }
    else {
        alert('Dropdown is NOT visible, so do something else...');
    }
});
```

Can anyone see how this can be acheived with this plugin? Can I search the DOM for some class or something?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can seek class "dropdown-open".
Might be:

```
if ($(".dropdown-open").length > 0) {
 // A dropdown is opened
} else {
 // No opening dropdown
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The plugin uses a unique id for each dropdown, i.e., dropdown-1, dropdown-2, dropdown-3, etc.

You may use this id to target a specific dropdown. Check wether its css `display` is `block` or `none`.